# Black background for text

Tags: html, css

I am getting a black background for a text inside a div. I don't know why. 
the code and style for the div is.

```
<div class="intro_div">
            <div>Intro text goes here</div>
</div>
```

the style for the div is

```
.intro_div{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 500px;
}
```

The output is 
[image]

Comment: I didn't see that in your given code. https://jsfiddle.net/16bobgmu/ May be some other code/css may effect it.

Comment: check the computed css on body tag

Comment: It would be better if you can provide all your files online.

Comment: Figured the problem. its because another div in background. i use that div to load a video in background.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use background-color, not color:

```
.intro_div{
  background-color: #fff;
  color:black;
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 500px;
}
```

Also, try using known names in your CSS, so it will be more readble.
So instead of

```
background-color: #fff;
```

Try using

```
background-color: white;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check using Google chrome or Mozilla Firefox debugger tools to see if the div inherits other css rules?

It may not have css rules for intro_div but instead have rules for the div class.

On Mozilla, you can right click on the text, view element, and analyze the css rules on lower right of the debugger window.

Since you're using chrome, go through all the rules in the Styles tab on the right of your window. It may be the case that one of your other style sheets is causing this (e.g. The material design style sheet). Better identify what is setting it to black first before explicitly setting it to white. It should be unset by default.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you had the wrong CSS background-color property. It should be

```
background-color:
```

not 
`color`:

https://jsfiddle.net/fergnab/16bobgmu/1/

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in this code for black bg. It must be coming from elsewhere i.e parent element. Select div with intro class and check all styles on right hand side to the bottom, looking for background-color property in any style.

Answer (score 0):

You should take white background color and black as color like this :

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

    .intro_div{
      background-color: #fff;
      color:black;
      font-size: xx-large;
      text-align: center;
      height: 500px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      line-height: 500px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="intro_div">
            <div>Intro text goes here</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```